# Use host (Mac) docker from VSCode Devcontainer (debian)

Tags: docker, dockerfile, debian, docker-in-docker, vscode-devcontainer

I am using a `from debian` in a VSCode devcontainer on my mac:

https://github.com/free2z/free2z/pull/12/files#diff-13bd9d7a30bf46656bc81f1ad5b908a627f9247be3f7d76df862b0578b534fc6

```
FROM debian

# Create sudo user "dev"
ARG USERNAME=dev
ARG USER_UID=1000
ARG USER_GID=$USER_UID

# Create the `dev` user
# https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/add-nonroot-user
RUN groupadd --gid $USER_GID $USERNAME \
    && useradd --uid $USER_UID --gid $USER_GID -m $USERNAME \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y sudo \
    && echo $USERNAME ALL=\(root\) NOPASSWD:ALL > /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME \
    && chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/$USERNAME
USER $USERNAME

# Install docker
RUN sudo apt install -y \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    gnupg \
    lsb-release
RUN sudo mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
RUN echo \
    "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
    $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
RUN sudo apt update
RUN sudo apt install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin
RUN sudo usermod -aG docker $USERNAME
```

I'm trying to use the host docker socket. By using a bind mount.

```
        "source=/var/run/docker.sock,target=/var/run/docker.sock,type=bind",
```

My non-root user in the docker group and docker works with sudo:

```
➜  free2z git:(metarepo) ✗ groups     
dev docker
➜  free2z git:(metarepo) ✗ docker ps     
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/containers/json": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
➜  free2z git:(metarepo) ✗ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                         COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS        PORTS     NAMES
9167a45c8223   vsc-free2z-597acf8d147e25327effb72c17e8d21f   "/bin/sh -c 'echo Co…"   20 hours ago   Up 20 hours             gallant_morse
```

Answer (score 0):

Root still owns the socket, you can chown it to the non-root user in your .devcontainer.json

```
"postCreateCommand": "sudo chown dev /var/run/docker.sock",
```